# Python SimpleHttpServer howto

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, simplehttpserver

**I have:** I created `index.html` - the simplest html page & launch my simple http server with `python -m SimpleHttpServer 8000`.

**I want:** make `index.html` use javascript which depends on JQuery.

**Problem:** Seems `SimpleHttpServer` doesn't load JS files. I mean if I write `<script src="myScript.js"/>` inside `index.html`  - `myScript.js` won't be loaded by browser.

**Question:** Why browser doesn't download JS files?

*P.S.* I use OSX Mavericks 10.9.4

Comment: Can you try to load the script in a different tab? Also can you check the console and the network tab for any errors/404?

Comment: @vaidik what do you mean by loading a script in a different tab?

Comment: @V_B: He means to just open http://localhost:8000/myScript.js directly in a browser tab, the same way you opened http://localhost:8000/

Comment: Also, apologies if this is a stupid question, but… you did put `myScript.js` (with exactly that spelling and capitalization) in the same directory as `index.html`, right?

Comment: Can you rename `index.html` for a while and then go to http://localhost:8000 to see the list of files you see in the browser? Can you tell us if `myScript.js` is in that list.

Comment: @V_B: Until you try vaidik's original suggestion and tell us what happened, there's no way anyone can go any further helping you, except by reading your mind or making an incredibly lucky guess.

Comment: @vaidik no, there isn't any errors at console or network tabs.

Comment: @vaidik I can access it via `localhost:8000/myScript.js`. But `index.html` doesn't fetch it for some reason

Comment: @vaidik if I rename `index.html` it propose me a list of all files from the root directory. The problem is that if I choose `index.html` it doesn't execute referenced javascript file

Comment: Another obvious question - is the server you have written actually getting a GET request for that javascript file ? What the browser will do is make a GET request per file it needs - so your server will need to be able to serve every file - not just index.html

Comment: Hmm.. Its getting difficult to understand what's going on. Can you list down the contents of your directory as you see them after running `ls -l` and also the contents of `index.html`?

Comment: Have you overidden the do_GET method. If you are using the SimpleHTTPServer - you can actually write the code to serve the files from your disk.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 sorry for misunderstanding. I haven't write any server by my own. I just use standard python server on osx.

Answer (score 1):

I hope starting python server in the correct folder path of index.html file should solve the issue.

**P.S** *I have faced the same issue and realised that I have started the python server in the parent folder of `index.html` file which didn't have the `script.js` file*